# Subsonic - query with optional parameters

Tags: optional-parameters, subsonic2.2, option-type

Using C# 3.5 through VS 2008 and subsonic 2.2.
Anyone know if it's possible to create a subsonic query that essentially has an 'IF' in the middle of it, depending on whether a passed parameter was, for example, greater than zero.

For example, a delete method that has two passed parameters - A and B.

I want something like (pseudo code)

```
DELETE from Products
Where productId = A
if(B > 0)
{
AND ProductAttributeId = B
}
```

Obviously it wouldn't need the actual 'IF' clause in there but that's the essence of what I'm trying to do with subsonic. I know I can just have two different queries depending on whether the parameter is there or not but I was wondering if there's a cleaner way of doing it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how I usually do it - it's not two queries, but one `SqlQuery` with optionally added constraints:

```
SqlSquery q = DAL.DB.Delete()
    .From<DAL.Product()
    .Where(DAL.Product.ProductIdColumn).IsEqualTo(A);
if (B > 0)
{
    q.And(DAL.Product.ProductAttributeIdColumn).IsEqualTo(B);
}
q.Execute();
```

There may be a typo, I can't test this right now.